# How to find the new speed a vector needs to be travelling at?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm currently working on an investigation about applying velocity and position vectors to naval ships and aircraft (In a 2-dimensional plane). In my current question, I am tracking the motion of a ship (G) and a helicopter (N) and when they intersect.

The vector equation representing the helicopter is N = [24 - 7*t*, 12 + 24*t*] where *t* is the time in hours after the starting time of 9pm and the vector equation representing the motion of the ship is G = [15.5 + 8*t*, 5 + 15*t*]. On the graph of their vector equations the helicopter does not intersect with the ship due to it travelling too fast (originally 25km/h). For the purpose of the investigation, I am allowed to assume that the objects stay perfectly on their paths, therefore I can take the intersection point to be exactly (22.31, 17.78).

What the question asks is "What new speed the helicopter needs to be travelling at to intersect the ship and what time does the intersection occur?" (units in km and time, *t*, in hours) How exactly do I go about solving this?

Comment: With the ship travelling along $G=[15.5+8t,5+15t]$ I have doubts that its speed is $25km/h$. We better clarify that first. How do you calculate the speed of the ship and that of the helicopter ? Please use MathJax for better readability.

Comment: @KurtG OP's wording is a bit confusing. I think 25$\dfrac{km}{h}$ is the speed of the helicopter.

Comment: I meant kilometres per hour but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative approach:

Ignoring your specific reported speed of $25 km/h$, and taking your reported intersection point at face value, I should point out that there is some rounding error here.

For example, for the helicopter:

- $24 - 7t = 22.31 \implies t \approx 0.2414.$
- $12 + 24t = 17.78 \implies t \approx 0.2408.$

For the ship:

- $15.5 + 8t = 22.31 \implies t = 0.85125$.
- $5 + 15t = 17.78 \implies t = 0.852.$

So, neither the helicopter nor the ship will exactly hit the $(22.31,17.78)$ coordinate.

Ignoring this, the answer is simple.  Slow down the helicopter so that it's time to reach the intersection point equals the ship's time.

Since the relative times are

- helicopter : $t \approx 0.2408$
- ship : $t \approx 0.852$

Multiply the helicopter's speed by $~\displaystyle \frac{0.2408}{0.852}$.  Then, they both reach the intersection point at the exact same time.  And the intersection **time** will be the time originally scheduled for the ship to reach that point.

---

The remainder of this answer shows the mathematical approach needed to calculate the intersection point, and times exactly.  It will be assumed that the scalar $s$ is applied to the helicopter's speed, to slow it down.  So, $0 < s < 1.$

Then, the helicopter's position is $(24 - 7st, 12 + 24st).$

The ship's position is $(15.5 + 8t, 5 + 15t).$

So, you have two equations in the two unknowns $s$ and $t$ that need to be solved.  Assume that the intersection point is $A,B$, which is some unknown value that has yet to be determined.

Then

$$24 - 7st = A = 15.5 + 8t \implies 8t + 7st = 8.5. \tag1 $$

$$12 + 24st = B = 5 + 15t \implies 15t - 24st = 7. \tag2 $$

Now comes the tricky part.  The RHS of (1) and (2) above represent two equations in the two unknowns, $s,t.$

The simplest approach is to multiply the first equation by $(24)$ and multiply the 2nd equation by $(7)$, and then add them together.

This will result in an equation where the $(st)$ term has been eliminated, so that $t$ can be directly calculated.  Then, everything will fall into place.  Following this approach, you have that

$$192t + 168st = 204. \tag3 $$

$$105t - 168st = 49.  \tag4 $$

(3) and (4) may now be added together.

$$297t = 253 \implies t = \frac{253}{297} = \frac{23}{27} \approx 0.85185. \tag5 $$

Plugging this value of $t$ back into (4) above yields

$$\left[105 \times \frac{23}{27}\right] - \left[168 \times \frac{23}{27} \times s\right] = 49 \implies s = \frac{13}{46}. \tag6 $$

So, with $~\displaystyle t = \frac{23}{27}, ~s = \frac{13}{46},~$ the time taken by the ship and helicopter will both be $t$.  Here, the speed of the helicopter will have been slowed down, by the factor $s$.

Now, the exact intersection point $A,B$ may be calculated, using (1) and (2) above.

$$A = 15.5 + 8t = 15 + \left(\frac{27}{54}\right) + \left(\frac{8 \times 23 \times 2}{54}\right)
= 15 + \frac{395}{54} = 22 + \frac{17}{54}.$$

$$B = 5 + 15t = 5 + \left(15 \times \frac{23}{27}\right)
= 5 + \frac{345}{27} = 17 + \frac{7}{9}.$$

Comment: @Jjcoolgames You have to be prepared that when you change a vector equation, you **may** have altered the intersection point, which implies that you can no longer assume that (for example), the helicopter *normally* gets there first.  With the generic approach that I used in the 2nd part of this answer, this translates to the idea that you may end up with $s > 1$, rather than $s < 1.$  When this happens, one approach is to interpret the result as signifying that the time taken will be $(st)$ instead of $t$.  ...see next comment

Comment: @Jjcoolgames Then, you also interpret the result as signifying that the ship needs to be slowed down by having the scalar of $(1/s)$ applied to the ship's speed.

Comment: Thank you for the very easy to follow answer! I believe I entered the wrong vector equation for the ship by accident (it is actually [19.5 + 8t, 12.5 + 15t]) but the same principle still applies. If I know the intersection point, I can get the distance between the ship and intersection point (around 5.98km) and divide it by its speed (17 km/h) to get the time it takes to reach the intersection point which is 0.352 hours. Since the helicopter reaches the intersection point at the same time, I divided the distance (6.02km) between it and the intersection point to find its speed of 17.1 km/h.

Comment: @Jjcoolgames Here, you have to be careful.  Using the generic approach in the 2nd part of my answer, you **do not initially know the intersection point**.  Instead, you first determine $t$.  Then, you determine $s$.  Then, you determine $A,B$ which represents the intersection point.  Then, if $s > 1$, rather than $< 1$, you follow the altered approach indicated by my comments, following this answer.

Comment: Yes I believe your method is correct for a generic case, but does this mean my method works for my specific case?

Comment: @Jjcoolgames No.  To the best of my knowledge, assuming that your initial knowledge is limited to the $x,y$ location vectors of the ship and helicopter, you **never** know the intersection point, *up front*.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for your time either way!

Answer (score 0):

For the helicopter, the velocity is along the unit vector

$ \hat{v_1} = \dfrac{ \langle -7, 24 \rangle }{\sqrt{7^2 + 24^2}} = \langle - \dfrac{7}{25} , \dfrac{24}{25} \rangle $

So if its speed along that direction is $s_1$, then its position as a function of time is

$ N(t) = \langle 24, 12 \rangle + t s_1 \hat{v_1} $

For the ship, its position is given as

$ G(t) = \langle 15.5 , 5 \rangle + t \langle 8, 15 \rangle $

If the helicopter and the ship are at the same position at the same time, then

$ \langle 24, 12 \rangle + t s_1 \hat{v_1} = \langle 15.5 , 5 \rangle + t \langle 8, 15 \rangle $

which reduces to

$ \langle 8.5 , 7 \rangle = t \bigg( \langle 8, 15 \rangle - s_1 \langle - \dfrac{7}{25} , \dfrac{24}{25} \rangle \bigg) $

If the vector on the left of the above equation is a multiple of the vector on the right, then the following determinant is $0$

$ \begin{vmatrix} 8.5 && 8 + \dfrac{7}{25} s_1 \\ 7 && 15 - \dfrac{24}{25} s_1 \end{vmatrix} = 0 $

Expanding the determinant,

$ 8.5 ( 15 - \dfrac{24}{25} s_1 ) - 7 (8 + \dfrac{7}{25} s_1 ) = 0 $

and this simplifies to

$ 71.5 - \dfrac{253}{25} s_1 = 0 $

From which, $s_1 \approx  7.0652 $

And this gives

$ t = \dfrac{8.5}{8 - 1.9783} = 0.8518  $

If we substitute the speed $s_1$ and the time $t$ , we get the meeting position

$ N(t) = \langle 24 +  (0.8518) (7.0652) (- \dfrac{7}{25} ) , 12 + (0.8518)(7.0652) \dfrac{24}{25} \rangle = \langle 22.31 , 17.78 \rangle $

Substitute $t$ in $G(t)$

$G(t) = \langle 15.5 + 8 (0.8518) , 5 + 15 (0.8518) \rangle = \langle 22.31, 17.78 \rangle $